# Redirect output of EXE started by Task Scheduler with ability of correct closing when "Run whether user is logged on or not" option is checked

Tags: windows, redirect, cmd, exe, scheduler

### I need:

1. Run `PROGRAM.EXE` in Windows thru **Task Scheduler** with option "***Run whether user is logged on or not***"
2. **Redirect output** of the EXE to text file thru `>>`
3. Be able to **close the EXE correctly** (soft-kill) without forcing to kill the process (hard-kill like a `taskkill /F`).
   Best would be thru the "End" menu item in Task Scheduler.

---

### I tried this:

(tested in WindowsServer 2008 R2 and Windows 7 Professional)

> Experiment 1 (In Task Scheduler)

Program/script: `PROGRAM.EXE`

Add arguments: `arg1 arg2 >> C:\PATH\OUTPUT.LOG 2>&1`

Start in: `C:\PATH\`

> Result:

No - Not output.

Yes - Closing thru "End" menu WORK as needed (soft-kill).

---

> Experiment 2

Program/script: `CMD`

Add arguments: `/C PUSHD C:\PATH && PROGRAM.EXE arg1 arg2 >> OUTPUT.LOG 2>&1`

> Result:

Yes - Output was OK.

No - "End" menu closed just CMD.EXE, but not PROGRAM.EXE

---

In both above cases I tried it with "*Run with highest privileges*" option checked.

> Experiment 3

`CMD> taskkill /T /PID 17640 (ProcessID of the CMD)`

> Result:
> ERROR: The process with PID 9172 (child process of PID 17640) could not be terminated.
> Reason: This process can only be terminated forcefully (with /F option).
> ERROR: The process with PID 17640 (child process of PID 13380) could not be terminated.
> Reason: One or more child processes of this process were still running.

This work only if "***Run only when user is logged on***" option is checked (both processes correctly closed).

---

## What to do?

Thanks.

Comment: A console window is effectively owned by the process that allocates the console session. Other processes attached to the console do not own it. Within a terminal session, it's possible to map the owning process to the console window (e.g. "program.exe" or "cmd.exe") and send the window a `WM_CLOSE` message or `WM_SYSCOMMAND` : `SC_CLOSE` message. The console session responds by sending attached processes a `CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT`. They have 5 seconds to handle the event and exit gracefully before getting forcefully terminated.

Comment: But window messages are isolated to a single terminal session, and "run whether user is logged on or not" runs in session 0, the non-interactive services session. Perhaps it will work to create a temporary task that runs taskkill.exe in session 0.

Comment: I tried, but I can't make that suggestion work. It's probably because the task scheduler uses a separate logon session with its own window station. taskkill.exe should be able to enumerate and connect to other window stations in a session, but it could be that this doesn't work in session 0 because it's a disconnected session -- just speculation. You'll probably just have to forcefully end the accessible process tree (sans orphaned processes), via `schtasks /end /tn taskname` or `taskkill /F /T /PID taskpid`.

Comment: Which version of Windows are you using? For me in Windows 10, the task scheduler's "end" (e.g. `schtasks /end`)  has no problem terminating child processes of a task as long as they're not orphaned, which is basically the same as `taskkill.exe /F /T`.

Comment: Tkank you.

@ErykSun
`taskkill /F /T /PID <cmd_pid>` close both of processes, so I suppose that `PROGRAM.EXE` is not an orphaned process.
`schtasks /end` in Windows 7 Pro and WindowsServer 2008 R2 closed only `CMD.EXE` process.
Sending the `WM_CLOSE` message to PROGRAM.EXE is exactly, what I need to do. But how? I need to **close it correctly**, so I cannot use `taskkill /F`.

@Mofi
Put `C:\PATH` into **Start in** and set **Add arguments** as you suggest, did the same job. Output is OK, but soft-termination not work.